# R: find Median and Mean of each LOOP of Fibonacci to N elements 1:n. Compare Median and Mean

Tags: r, switch-statement, fibonacci

We have Fibonacci:

```
  fib=function(n){
  x = c(1,1)
  for(i in 3:n) x[i] = x[i-1] + x[i-2]
  return(x)
}
```

Also we have Switch function:

```
centre <- function(x, type) {
  switch(type,
    mean = mean(x),
    median = median(x))
}
```

Now we can find for example Fibonacci of 10 and take a look for mean and median of 10:

```
fib(10)
centre(fib(10), "mean")
centre(fib(10), "median")
```

OUTPUT:

```
##  [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55
## [1] 14.3
## [1] 6.5

# For Fib(10) Mean > Median
```

The question will be: (how to do it for 9/8/7/6 Fibonacci or for 50 numbers?)

Now we have to add in this loop: **switch** statement to calculate the mean and the median.
In each turn of the loop check whether the mean or median has the larger value and print out the larger of the two values

So I can not understand how to improve the code and integrate there this **swith**

May be someone can give a hint how to do that in R?
It seems that we can get all "mean" and "median" for each Fibonacci number (in our case for every 1:10) and compare them by creating additional Function

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? I'm surprised not to see `mean()` or `median()` in your attempt... And why the Python tag?

Comment: The `mean` and `median` of what? Why do you "have to" use `switch`?

Comment: @Oliver In general, you gotta' give it a try before you get to open up the gates of StackOverflow. ;)

Comment: Guidance for getting homework help [is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/903061), but oaxacamatt's  comment sums it up pretty well. Read through the documentation at `?switch`, paying special attention to the Examples at the bottom (and maybe also examples you were provided by your instructor?). Give it a go. If you are still stuck, show us what you tried. But when your task is to use `switch` to compare the `mean` and the `median` and you don't have a single one of those functions in your attempt, you need to do a little more work on your own before we can effectively help you.

Comment: It seems I am "thinking" wrong way. First I created Switch Function: `centre <- function(x, type) {
  switch(type,
    mean = mean(x),
    median = median(x)
}`
Then used another Function for Fibonacci:
`fib=function(n){
  x = c(1,1)
  for(i in 3:n) x[i] = x[i-1] + x[i-2]
  return(x)
}`

Let’s say I want to find first 10 Fibonacci numbers.
The task is to find the mean or median using switch statement.
I see that I can find whole vector median and mean by:
`centre(fib, "mean")`
`centre(fib, "median")`
But how to do the same, but with every “loop”?

Comment: That's great info! Please edit your question to include all this instead of burying it in a comment.

Comment: I'd also suggest that your `centre` function calculates **either** the mean or the median, using the `switch` function to decide which. But what you need to do is calculate **both** the mean and the median, compare them, and then use the `switch` function to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make your `for` loop more than one line.

```
fib=function(n){
  x = c(1,1)
  for(i in 3:n) { ## add {} to do more stuff in the loop
    x[i] = x[i-1] + x[i-2]
    current_mean = centre(x, "mean")
    current_median = centre(x, "median")
    ## Insert code here to compare the current mean and median
    ## and print the larger
  }
  return(x)
}
```